# How to limit TOC level in wiki in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I cannot see here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#table-of-contents-toc-for-wiki-pages
any rule to do something like that:

```
[[__TOC__ limit:3]]
```

To limit the level of collected headers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and found a workaround. [This ADO help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#table-of-contents-toc-for-wiki-pages) mentions "Only Markdown headings are considered for TOC (HTML heading tags aren't considered)."

For example, to eliminate the duplicate page title in the embedded TOC, I used `<h1>page title</h1>` instead of `#page title`. This eliminated the page title from the embedded TOC, but the page title still rendered in the same visual style on the wiki page. The same approach worked for subtitles: using `<h3>subtitle</h3>` instead of `###subtitle` rendered the subtitle appearing like a subtitle in the wiki page, but kept it out of the TOC.

It's a manual approach but it helped keep the TOC simplified which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately this isn't supported and this closed item, "[Specify the TOC depth level](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Specify-the-TOC-depth-level/507338?space=21&entry=problem)", suggests it will not be supported.